# Difference between query, native query, named query and typed query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, native-sql

What are the differences between a query, a native query, a named query and a typed query? Does the 'alone-standing' query even exist, or is it just an abbreviation? In my mind, a native Query is a query written in simple sql, whereas a named query relates to entities (hibernate-mapping). Can someone explain this briefly?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**Query**

Query refers to JPQL/HQL query with syntax similar to SQL generally used to execute DML statements(CRUD operations).

In JPA, you can create a query using `entityManager.createQuery()`. You can look into [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) for more detail.

In Hibernate, you use `session.createQuery()`"

**NativeQuery**

Native query refers to actual sql queries (referring to actual database objects). These queries are the sql statements which can be directly executed in database using a database client.

JPA : `entityManager.createNativeQuery()`
Hibernate (Non-JPA implementation): `session.createSQLQuery()`

**NamedQuery**

Similar to how the constant is defined. NamedQuery is the way you define your query by giving it a name. You could define this in mapping file in hibernate or also using annotations at entity level.

**TypedQuery**

TypedQuery gives you an option to mention the type of entity when you create a query and therefore any operation thereafter does not need an explicit cast to the intended type. Whereas the normal `Query` API does not return the exact type of Object you expect and you need to cast.

Comment: Is there any performance, throughput, memory consumption, load app server differences between the different queries? I think that NamedQuery memory consumption is greater than query, but I can not say where is the limit of queries to opt in favor of one or another. Could you explain? thanks in advance

Comment: For lack of a better place to mention this, I'll add that one should be very careful converting Hibernate _non-native_ queries to native queries, specifically w/respect to how null values are handled when returned from native queries.  My team recently saw some weird _SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet_ and _ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY_ errors when potential nulls were not accounted for.  Maybe someone will stumble upon this comment and reach a resolution to their problem faster knowing this little gotcha.

Comment: In createNativeQuery(), we can pass class type. That means our query result is mapped to the class which we mentioned? Can you please tell me how that works.