# Spring Boot JPA: how do query a JSON column in a table

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table `casemessage` and has following columns. And I am trying to search/query `JSON` column using `Spring Framework JPA`..

1. id
2. created_by
3. created_utc
4. from_id
5. message
6. status
7. case_id

Here the `status` column stores list of `JSON` strings. For example:

```
 1. [{"user_id": 1, "status": "sent"}, {"user_id": 2, "status": "delete"}]
 2. [{"user_id": 3, "status": "delete"}, {"user_id": 2, "status": "sent"},{"user_id": 1, "status": "received"}]
 3. [{"user_id": 1, "status": "received"}, {"user_id": 2, "status": "sent"}]
 4. [{"user_id": 1, "status": "delete"}, {"user_id": 3, "status": "sent"}]
```

I am trying to query the `casemessage` table to get all the rows where `user_id` is `1` and `status` is not `delete`

Using `MySQL` query, I am able to query the table and get back expected results.

Here is the query, which I tried:

```
 select * from casemessage  where case_Id=1 and id not in(select id from cwot.casemessage where json_contains(status, '{"status" :"delete"}') and json_contains(status, '{"user_id" : 1}'));
```

When I tried this using `Spring Framework JPA` (`Spring Boot`), I got back an exception when running the application. Here is the statement that I tied:

```
    @Query("select c from CaseMessage c  where c.caseId=?1 and c.id not in(select cm.id from CaseMessage cm where json_contains(status, '{\"status\": \"delete\"}') and json_contains(status, '{\"user_id\": ?2}'))")
    List<CaseMessageResponse> getAllCaseMessages(long caseId, long userId);
```

The error that I am getting back is:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 172 [select c from com.cwot.domain.CaseMessage c  where c.caseId=?1 and c.id not in(select cm.id from com.cwot.domain.CaseMessage cm where json_contains(status, '{"status": "delete"}') and json_contains(status, '{"user_id": ?1}'))]
```

Can some one help me with this.?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if a value exists in json encode array in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132714/check-if-a-value-exists-in-json-encode-array-in-mysql)

Comment: @e4c5, I am looking at the JPA point of view. My query works in MySQL

Comment: that does not make any difference. This is a situation that's not suited for JSON

Comment: I have a doubt. What if I need to check if there is any key called status, then how to check that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use native query to use database functions like json_contains:

```
@Query("select c from CaseMessage c  where c.caseId=?1 and c.id not in(select cm.id from CaseMessage cm where json_contains(status, '{\"status\": \"delete\"}') and json_contains(status, '{\"user_id\": ?2}'))", nativeQuery = true)
    List<CaseMessageResponse> getAllCaseMessages(long caseId, long userId);
```

or with the @NativeQuery annotation

for more information :

[Difference between query, native query, named query and typed query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236664/difference-between-query-native-query-named-query-and-typed-query)

Comment: When I ran using this statement, I get back an error saying `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist`

Comment: you must modify your query, it must become a native one

Comment: What if I don't want to use native query? Is there any solution?

Comment: Hi @LaurentGrousset... What if I want to pass a parameter here - `json_contains(status, '{\"status\": \"delete\"}')`? Instead of static string **delete**, I want some dynamic string? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way I was able to solve this was by using
`JSON_CONTAINS(json, JSON_QUOTE(?1))` along with `nativeQuery=true`

That way, I was able to add the additional double quotes required for querying